# Trying to use a xpages dynamic view panel with search on fields value

Tags: search, dynamic, view, xpages, field

I have created an xPages custom control based on Dynamic View Panel. I then added 2 comboboxes filled with various values (States, Departments) and an editbox field and a Search button. I then coded the follow to return the search string  onto a computed "Search in view results" for the panel.

```
var tmpArray = new Array("");

var cTerms = 0;
if(viewScope.categoryText1 != null) {
    if ( viewScope.categoryText1.trim() != "") {
        tmpArray[cTerms++] = "(FIELD State CONTAINS \"" + viewScope.categoryText1 + "\")";
    }
}

if(viewScope.categoryText2 != null ){
    if ( viewScope.categoryText2.trim() != "") {
        tmpArray[cTerms++] = "(FIELD Department = \"" + viewScope.categoryText2 + "\")";
    }
}
if(viewScope.searchString  != null ) {
    if ( viewScope.searchString != "") {
        tmpArray[cTerms++] = "( \"" + viewScope.searchString  + "\")";
    }
}
qstring = tmpArray.join(" AND ").trim();

viewScope.queryString = qstring; // this just displays the query
return qstring // this is what sets the search property
```

The search works for the editbox field values but not for the strings generated by the comboboxes: 'FIELD State CONTAINS "some state"' or 'FIELD Department = "some deptname"'. These search strings return an empty view.

The Column names match the underlying Notesview (both programmatically and column title).

I think this might have something to do with what are the column names surfaced by the Dynamic View Panel but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full text search looks in *document fields* for search strings, not in column values.

So, make sure fields State and Department contain the strings you are looking for.

Do you use aliases? Maybe you save abbreviation for State in document only but user can select State's full name for search...

Comment: That's it! I need to look at the field names in the document, not the column names.